# jasmine-node error TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jasmine-node

i am getting this error from last two days where as the code is same and installation procedure is also same , is this because of any new update in jasmine-node

```
            /var/www/jasmine-node# jasmine-node --verbose --junitreport --noColor spec

            /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node/lib/jasmine-node/reporter.js:336
              jasmineNode.TeamcityReporter.prototype = new jasmine.TeamcityReporter;
                                                       ^
            TypeError: undefined is not a function
                at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node/lib/jasmine-node/reporter.js:336:44
                at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node/lib/jasmine-node/reporter.js:342:3)
                at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
                at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
                at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
                at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
                at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
                at require (module.js:380:17)
                at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node/lib/jasmine-node/index.js:34:21)
                at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

Comment: is your teamcity reporter enabled?

Comment: how can i check if its enabled

Comment: sorry to say but i am not getting it

Comment: i'd check with jasmine node's support.

Comment: node --version
v0.10.23
gives me this....and 
jasmine-node --version ....gives me the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57015/discussion-between-daniel-a-white-and-user310685).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

downgrading it to older version solved the issue for me

```
      jasmine-node@1.14.2
```

Sources:

[jasmine-node shows error when ran from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553915/jasmine-node-shows-error-when-ran-from-command-prompt)

https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters/issues/63

https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node/pull/332